# Chemfig MakeBraces error

Tags: chemfig

I want to make polymer structures with chemfig like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
\edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
\edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1#
2)/2}%
\chemmove{%
\node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right.$};%
\node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
\setpolymerdelim()
\chemfig[][scale=0.5]{-[@{op, 0.75}]O-[:30](=[:120]O)-*6(-=-(-(=[:60]O)-[:-30]O--[:30]-[@{cl, 0.25}])=-=)}
\makebraces[8pt, 8pt]{\!\!n}{op}{cl}\\
\end{document}
```

Overleaf makes the polymer structures and also the brackets, but gives me a lot of error messages:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \makebraces.
>
> l.70 \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1#
>
> You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
>   Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
>   are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

Does anyone know, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`chemfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package has been recently updated, and version 1.33 includes `\polymerdelim` macro with the following syntax:

```
\polymerdelim[<keys>=<values>]{<node1>}{<node2>}
```

For more detailed info on usage refer to section *12.4 Draw a ploymer element* on p. 43 of the [chemfig manual](http://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf). I'm not sure whether Overleaf has already updated the package on their side or not, but I'd stick to the new syntax anyway. I also wouldn't use scaling; instead, make the bonds a bit shorter.

So, in your case for the structure of polyethylene terephthalate I suggest the following (I also adjusted angles a bit):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep = 1.75em,
        double bond sep = 0.3em,
        bond join = true,
    }
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
    -[@{op, 0.5}]O-[:60](=[:120]O)-*6(-=-(-(=[:60]O)-[:-60]O--[:60]-[@{cl, 0.5}])=-=)
}
\polymerdelim[height = 32pt, depth = 4pt, indice = \!\!n]{op}{cl}

\end{document}
```

[image]